# What is the best practice for creating Custom Exceptions?

Tags: c#

When creating Custom Exceptions is it best practice to make a separate class file for each and every Custom Exception, or append the Custom Exceptions to the end of the class file that they relate to, or create a file (eg. CustomExceptions.cs) and add the Custom Exceptions there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One class per file is always a good rule.

The other basics:

- Mark your exception as `[Serializable]`
- Overload all the System.Exception constructors
- Don't inherit from System.ApplicationException

Answer (score 1):

Well ... I would say that you should follow the rule of one class per file, except in case if this exception is just for "internal" functionality in your class. Then you can make it declared inside the class. However, if exposed by any means to outside world, separate it from the class. This exposure could also be seen from the actual probability that this exception goes unhanded to the users of your class. In this case, I would also expose it and would not declare it inside.

Comment: You have no control over what catches your exception, I would avoid declaring exceptions as nested classes

Comment: You do if you are the one writing the code, and there is only one public method for example. In this case, you can wrap your excetions(s) in possibly meaningful exceptions to outside world. Big problem with this approach is that someone could write another method on the class and "foget" to handle the exception, so ... I also don't recommend this approach, to say honestly

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, one class per file rule is ideal. Another way to think of it, if you have a large application consisting of many modules, you will have multiple namespaces and it's important to keep the exceptions that a certain class method (or set of classes/methods) can throw within their respective namespaces. This makes the code more readable and the reasoning behind your custom exceptions easier to decipher for other developers ... Or for you in 6 months when you forgot why you made half of them :)